# Commenting on a test review question automatically scolds you with "STOP! Look and listen" - Why?

Tags: discussion, review, comments, design, review-queue

I stumbled over a [review question, which turned out to be a Test question](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/804778).

I tried to write a comment that OP might consider using the older, 4.10 kernel, since there seem to be a lot of issues with the 4.13 kernel on 16.04.

However, that was deemed as "not listening" by the review test system.

Why is it that any comment one posts on a test question (that is considered a quality question) should fail it ?

Should we not encourage meaningful comments ?

I find this especially "loaded", since test questions obscure *existing* comments...

Comment: Oddly, it's ok to comment on some audit types but not on others. (On the ok ones, you get an alert that it's an audit and not a real post.)